# Is there a function in Tensorflow can do the following math?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two tensors, `x` and `y`, of shape `[B, D]`. I want to do something like the following code

```py
B, D = x.shape
x = tf.expand_dims(x, 1)  # [B, 1, D]
y = tf.expand_dims(y, -1) # [B, D, 1]
z = x * y                 # [B, D, D]
z = tf.reshape(z, (B, D**2))
```

Is there a function in Tensorflow that already does this?

Comment: Not that I know of, but you can make this a function and decorate it with `tf.function`

Comment: Can you clarify what _"this"_ is?

Comment: The code that you have posted is already using TensorFlow, what exactly is the issue with it? If you want to do it "in one line", you can do `z = tf.reshape(x[:, tf.newaxis] * y[:, :, tf.newaxis], (tf.shape(x)[0], -1))` (if you think that is somehow better).

Comment: I thought this is a fairly common math operation that multiplies each element in the second dimension of `x` by those of `y`. Therefore, I wondered if there is a function in tensorflow that already done it.